# How to get rid of unknown smiley bar in Windows Live Messenger?

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-messenger

Does anyone know what this thing is and how to get rid of it?

[image: Smiley bar]

Thanks

edit: It seems to be related to "funpartyfactory"
news:Your.buddy.sent.you.a.cool.Emoticon,.to.get.it.click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall SweetIM for Messenger and SweetIM Toolbar.

It spams contacts with news:Your.buddy.sent.you.a.cool.Emoticon,.to.get.it.click -random URL here-

Additional details at [the Spybot forum.](http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?t=16087)

Answer (score 1):

Some how you must have installed it. First thing I would do is run an anti virus. I suspect that's what you have.

Comment: Sadly this garbage is not detected by most scanners.